# cron задача на исполнение .php не выполняется

Tags: cron, ispmanager

Пытаюсь на хостинге [reg.ru](https://reg.ru) в панели управления `ispManager` создать `cron` задачу на выполнение одного .php файла. Вроде создаю задачу, но она не выполняется.

Исполняемый файл лежит в корне[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а команда задана таким образом[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде, я дал необходимые разрешение, но даже исполнение не работает

Comment: А вы уверены, что команда php запускается в том же каталоге, в каком находится файл counterupdate.php? Я вот не уверен. Во-вторых, вы уверены что команда php вообще существует? В документации reg.ru такую команду например не используют https://www.reg.ru/support/hosting-i-servery/yazyki-programmirovaniya-i-skripty/planirovschik-cron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А где ваша крон задача? Сервер работает по другому, для команды должны написать։

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/www-root/data/www/vashdomen.ru/counterupdate.php
```

в вашем случае։

/* 
  /opt/php/5.3/bin/php   зависит от того ,какую версию PHP используйте
*/

```
/opt/php/5.3/bin/php -f /var/www/user_id/data/www/vashdomen.ru/counterupdate.php
```

Или можете вызвать через `GET` т.е

```
/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null https://vashdomen.ru/counterupdate.php
```

в вашем случае։

```
wget -q -O - https://vashdomen.ru/counterupdate.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

PS путь `/var/www/www-root/data/www/`  у вас может быть другим.

Comment: Я ввел путь до .php файла как вы указали, после, вручную выполнил задачу, и выдает такое `Could not open input file: /www/koronavirus.online/scripts/counterupdate.php`

Comment: @MidNightElf обновил ответ